# How to assign values to individual elements of python igraph list attributes?

Tags: python, graph, igraph

In python igraph, vertex and edge attributes can be any kind of python objects, e.g. lists, dictionaries. I created a vertex attribute where each vertex has a list value:

```
import igraph
g = igraph.Graph.Barabasi(10,5)
g.vs['foo'] = [[]]
```

Then I have (empty) lists for each vertex:

```
print g.vs['foo']
# [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Attribute values for individual vertices can referenced two ways:

```
print g.vs[0]['foo']
# []
print g.vs['foo'][0]
# []
```

If I want to do value assignement, it could be possible this way:

```
g.vs[0]['foo'] = ['bar']
g.vs['foo'][0] = ['bar']
```

The result, as I expect, the vertex number 0 has the value `['bar']`, while the other vertices have their attribute unchanged:

```
print g.vs[0]['foo']
# ['bar']
print g.vs['foo']
# [['bar'], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

My first, minor problem comes here: the assignement with the second way of referencing (i.e. attribute name > vertex index) doesn't work:

```
g.vs['foo'] = [[]]
g.vs['foo'][0] = ['bar']
print g.vs['foo'][0]
# []
print g.vs['foo']
# [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

But my main problem is that modifying the list of one vertex gives weird results:

```
g.vs['foo'] = [[]]
g.vs[0]['foo'].append('bar')
print g.vs['foo']
# [['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar']]
g.vs['foo'] = [[]]
g.vs[0]['foo'] += ['bar']
print g.vs['foo']
# [['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar']]
```

Not only the attribute of vertex number 0, but all the vertices' attributes have been appended the value! This is not what I would expect. I can give values to attributes of individual vertices this way:

```
g.vs['foo'] = [[]]
g.vs[0]['foo'] = g.vs[0]['foo'] + ['bar']
print g.vs['foo']
# [['bar'], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

But not with `append()`:

```
g.vs['foo'] = [[]]
g.vs[0]['foo'] = g.vs[0]['foo'].append('bar')
print g.vs['foo']
# [None, ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar'], ['bar']]
```

This is really surprising, the value 0 became `None`, while all the others has the list with the appended element. I think this behaviour is because the properties of pointers in python. If I initialize each value individually, everything works as I would expect intuitively:

```
for v in g.vs:
    v['foo'] = []
g.vs[0]['foo'].append('bar')
print g.vs['foo']
# [['bar'], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

So what is the recommended method to apply the `append()` on list vertex attributes? In case of addition of vertices, attributes are initialized to `None`. In this case, users need to write custom helper functions to keep the types of attributes consistent? Should we completely avoid initializing attributes this way: `g.vs['foo'] = [[]]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are experiencing the python list of list initialization using `*` operator.

```
>>> g.vs['foo'] = [[]]
```

Seems to be doing something like this (being 10 the number of vertices in your specific case):

```
>>> g.vs['foo'] = [[]] * 10
```

This may not work as you expect:

```
>>> [id(i) for i in g.vs['foo']]
[4348211640, 4348211640, 4348211640, 4348211640, 4348211640, 4348211640, 4348211640, 4348211640, 4348211640, 4348211640]
```

As you can see **all** the sublist are exactly the same list. All references are the same. So when you append to one of these sublists what you are really doing is modifying the same sublist.

A solution could be to create exactly number of vertices lists like this:

```
>>> g.vs['foo'] = [[] for _ in range(10)]
```

Then, if you print the references you'll see that they are actually different sublists:

```
>>> [id(i) for i in g.vs['foo']]
[4348211784, 4348212576, 4348212648, 4348212720, 4348212792, 4348212864, 4348212936, 4348213008, 4348213080, 4348213152]
```

Comment: Thank you for the examples! It's enlightening for me, and I should be more careful when writing code in Python.

Answer (score 2):

> My first, minor problem comes here: the assignement with the second way of referencing (i.e. attribute name > vertex index) doesn't work

It doesn't work because `g.vs["foo"]` returns a *copy* of the list that stores the value of the `foo` attribute, not the list itself. Therefore, `g.vs["foo"][0] = ["bar"]` will modify the copy and *not* the actual graph.